# what are the general front-end user cases can cause error?

Tags: magento-1.9, error

**A good working site gives error without changing the system a bit**

i have a maegnto site with 12 third party extesions,

it was working fine for last 45 days.

today suddenly it says

> "There has been an error processing your request".

what may be the reason? we haven't change anything in admin and magento sysem for last 45 days

**is there any general** front-end user cases can cause error ?

Comment: It can be *anything*. To find out more about the error, see the linked duplicate above.

Comment: no, i want to find any user case can cause these kind of error generally

Comment: That's impossible. "There has been an error processing your request" comes from a PHP exception. You can search your code base for "throw" to find all seversal thousand places where exceptions are thrown but it will still not cover all possibilities because there are also exceptions thrown by PHP itself.

Comment: @manokarthickkarthick are't you seeing any other errors other than `"There has been an error processing your request"

Comment: @manokarthickkarthick did you found solution ? or you can edit question with more details....

Comment: @BabyinMagento the problem is , i don't have access to see error log,  it was solved by out senior team, they don't want to give access to me until i learned enough magento

Comment: try with browser, means like `sitename.com/var/log/system.log`

Comment: it says forbidden